# Using CMAKE how to stop the "Debug" and "Release" subdirectories

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have specified my binary output directory with:

`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)`

Unfortunately, Visual Studio adds `Debug` and `Release` directories.

I do not want these.

The [documentation for CMAKE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) says:

> Multi-configuration generators (VS, Xcode) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory unless a generator expression is used.

But I am not sure exactly what that means.

How can I get Visual Studio to **not** add those directories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To directly answer your question: use a generator expression, as the documentation suggests. Here's an example:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY $<1:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin>)
```

`$<1:xxx>` is a genex which expands to `xxx`, so that means the final value will be what you want it to be.

However, be aware that this means that when building, binaries from the currently built configuration will overwrite those from the previous build, even if that was a different configuration. Are you sure you want that?

---

As a side note, that path you've specified is relative to the **source** directory. That sounds really unusual too, and could easily lead to problems. For example, if you generate multiple buildsystems from the same source (into different binary directories), the `.exe` files from them all will be stored in the same location, the last one built overwriting any previous ones. That sounds like a solid can of worms and a future maintenance nightmare.

While I do not know the details of your setup, I urge you to reconsider storing build artefacts in the source tree.

Comment: Great answer.  The issue with `debug` and `release` directories is that, currently on linux `make` doesn't create the same directories.  I am trying to make the final binary output directory the same on both platforms so any relative paths are the same.

Comment: @Startec Then I suggest adding them in the single-configuration generators instead of removing them from the multi-config ones.

Comment: when you say `that path you've specified is relative to the source directory` I thought that `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` *is* the source directory, but of the top most (i.e. root) of my project?

Comment: @Startec Yes it is, that's why I am saying it's unusual. You'd normally put binaries in the *binary* directory (`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`), not the source one.

Comment: So from the documentation, "For an in-source build, this would be the same as CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR." But what is the difference if, like me, you have an "out of source" build?

Comment: @Startec Source directory is where the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` is. Binary directory is where you have generated the buildsystem (such as the toplevel `.sln` file). All build artefacts should normally go into the binary dir, so that you can have as many buildsystems (= binary dirs) generated from one source dir as you want, and you can easily wipe the entire buildsystem by simply deleting the binary dir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158582/discussion-between-startec-and-angew).